# EarlGrey 2 - White Box Setup Simulator Crash on test run

Tags: ios, swift, earlgrey

I'm having trouble setting up EarlGrey2 for white box testing. 
I can setup blackbox fine, but when my bundle is attached to my test target, whenever a test is run the simulator crashes.

Xcode 11.4.1
iOS Sim: 12 & 13

## Steps:

### Black box: (Can succesfully run tests)

- https://github.com/google/EarlGrey/blob/earlgrey2/docs/setup.md
- https://medium.com/assertqualityassurance/earlgrey-2-direct-project-copy-setup-guide-8643207729cc

---

### White box: (Simulator crash on running test when bundle assigned to test target)

- https://github.com/google/EarlGrey/blob/earlgrey2/docs/white-boxing-setup-guide.md
- https://medium.com/assertqualityassurance/earlgrey2-setting-up-white-box-testing-capability-e90af19a3fee

---

- Create a new MAC bundle

  - SDK - iOS
  - Other Linker Flags: Add '-ObjC'
  - Bundle loader: '$(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/EarlGreyWhiteBoxTest.app/EarlGreyWhiteBoxTest'
  - User Header Search Paths: 'EarlGrey' (Recursive)
  - RunPath Search Paths: '@loader_path/Frameworks'
  - Build Phase -> Add a Target Dependency on the Application Under Test
  - Link Binary With Libraries -> Add a dependency on AppFramework.framework, set Status to Optional

At this point, both my bundle builds successfully, and I can still run EarlGrey black box tests

- Embed the Bundle into your application under test

  - Destination: Absolute Path
  - Path: $(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/../..//EarlGreyHelperBundles
  - Uncheck Copy only when installing
  - Code sign on copy

### Crash

***Simulator - iOS 13.4/usr/include/dispatch/once.h (dispatch_once()) - Line 84:***

[image]

> Thread 1: Exception: "An error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 \"The bundle “EG2Bundle” couldn’t be loaded because its executable couldn’t be located.\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle’s executable couldn’t be located., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle., NSBundlePath=/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/91EDC677-10D4-443D-A651-5775031EFBA0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/E2429B71-0C8E-4D84-81CE-1C4A39BDF291/EarlGreyWhiteBoxTest.app/EarlGreyHelperBundles/EG2Bundle.bundle, NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “EG2Bundle” couldn’t be loaded because its executable couldn’t be located.} was seen when loading the distant object categories bundle"

If I look manually, the bundle at the NSBundlePath does exist, so I assume i'm missing something because I'm not sure why this doesn't run.

Any help would be really appreciated!